# ValueError at /cart could not convert string to float: ''

Tags: python

I am new here and currently trying to make an add-to-cart page in my project but I am receiving this error as ValueError: could not convert string to float: "

It says that my error is coming from my views.py file line 128, so this is my line 128:

```
# Cart List Page
def cart_list(request):
    total_amt=0
    if 'cartdata' in request.session:
        for p_id,item in request.session['cartdata'].items():
            total_amt+=int(item['qty'])*float(item['price'])
        return render(request, 'cart.html',{'cart_data':request.session['cartdata'],'totalitems':len(request.session['cartdata']),'total_amt':total_amt})
    else:
        return render(request, 'cart.html',{'cart_data':'','totalitems':0,'total_amt':total_amt})
```

EDIT: I have looked up for solutions here but none worked for me and I did check there is no spacing in between either

When I refresh my page , I am getting an error like this:

```
ValueError at /cart
could not convert string to float: ''
```

Comment: See [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/9997212)

Comment: Paste your code into the question, select it, and press the code formatting button, which looks like this `{}`.

Comment: Thanks for teaching sir, I have uploaded the code with the error line in it

Comment: Well I think that you may better add a condition to check if `item['price']` is null or empty, put 0 in it. Good luck

Comment: The error message includes the value Python was unable to convert. So you should be able to discover the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`item['price']` contains an empty string. You should check if `item['price']` is a valid number:

```py
def check_num(num_type, value):
    try:
        return num_type(value)
    except ValueError:
        return None

for p_id, item in request.session['cartdata'].items():
    price = check_num(float, item['price'])
    if price is None:
        # Do something if price is not a valid number
        # e.g. set it to a default value, such as zero
        ...
  
    qty = check_num(int, item['qty'])
    if qty is None:
        # Do something if qty is not a valid number
        # e.g. set it to a default value, such as zero
        ...
    
    total_amt += qty * price
```

Comment: sorry for the super late reply, this helped me! I did not enter a default value in my models.py that is why it is having the error.